# Android: How can i put an image as a point style in a line graph?

Tags: android, achartengine, linegraph

I am plotting line graph using achart in which I need to put an image instead of a point style. How can i do that? Please help me?

```
protected void setRenderer(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, int[] colors, PointStyle[] styles) {
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    renderer.setPointSize(5f);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 20 });
    int length = colors.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
      r.setColor(colors[i]);
```

// I need to use image instead of styles here

```
r.setPointStyle(styles[i]);
  renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried now? Give some info about what you have tried with code if possible.  If you are using a custom view or drawing to canvas, you can draw the image bitmap at each of the end points of the line.

Comment: PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] { PointStyle.CIRCLE};

Comment: I am able to set point style as per above. But there i don't have an option to create a custom point style.I am not using a custom view to draw the image bitmap.

Comment: PointStyle is not available in Android SDK. Are you referring some other library?

Comment: I am using AchartEngine library.

Comment: did you find any help ?? I am trying this from the last 2 days but didnot find any help :-/